# android duplicate action menu on rotation of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment activity.
If the screen is two panel menu is menu1 else menu2.
If a rotate screen it becames one panel with menu1+menu2 when i rotate the action menu.
If is it possible to delete previous menu1.

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);      
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
```

Comment: err what? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: i cant post screenshot not enough reputation the screen has two menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
menu.clear();
```

... to clear and remove the menu items.

Comment: use menu.clear() in public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) not in public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)